# How to create a recursive exponential program that stores previous values of x

Tags: matlab, recursion, exponential

Say you wanted to create a recursive exponential program in Matlab with input `exponential(A,n)`, which should display the result `A^n`. Doing this recursively would mean you would have to work out the number of times to multiply A. However, is it possible to save values of previously worked out powers?

eg. To work out x^10 the program might work out x^5 and x^2. If it saved the values for x^5 and x^2 then to work out x^20 you only need to know what x^10 is, as x^5 and x^2 are already saved.

My question is, how would you go about writing the code to store these in an array of stored values, of dimensions `m x m x 20` where m is the size of the matrix `x`and 20 is the max value you want to store.

Comment: I don't think this is a worthwhile endeavour. Your likely to waste more cpu and ram than any gain.

Comment: This is a memoization problem. Do you intend to calculate only for integer values of `n`?